# Any pointers on making a downloader application? Preferably a Wix/MSI?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, download, installation

We've got an application we'd like our users to download.  Currently they click a link and download the EXE.  What we'd like to do is have a launchpad/downloader application that would be small and fast to download, which would then download and install the main application.

In a perfect world the downloader would be a MSI (so we could modify some MSI databases).

I'm a seriosu MSi newbie, so I've got no real ideas on where ot even start looking.  Any help or pointers woudl be much appreciated!

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write a bootstrap EXE, there's a little bit of documentation in [Windows Installer SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372866.aspx) or if you're wanting to take the lazy route, it looks like [MSI Factory](http://www.indigorose.com/msi-factory/features.php) includes WiX compatibility and a customizable bootstrap EXE including HTTP download options.

Alternatively if you're sticking to Open-Source, checkout ClickThrough in WiX. Doesn't seem to be much info on the WiX site, so I'm guessing it's part of WiX 3. But the description sounds similar to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com

Comment: dotNetInstaller is by far the best tool for creating bootstrappers, it's simple to use and very feature rich. We used it recently on a project and it was a life saver. I found alternatives such as GenerateBootstrapper and Wix 3.0 SetupBld were poor in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend writing your own exe, I would recommended using somethig you already have, the [Generic Boostrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163899.aspx) that comes with Visual Studio.

This separates the task of creating your msi.  Creating the boostrapper is then a more straightforward matter.  If you create your msi in Visual Studio, there is a UI to do this.  Otherwise you can create an msbuild task to do it yourself.